# Spring/JUnit serialization of double brace initialized ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, serialization

While writing a simple remoting test I've come up against a suprising situation involving DBI (double braces initialization) which I've been unable to fully understand, so I would ask for some assistance.

Consider the following code:

```
public class RemotingTest {

@Autowired
private RemotingTestController remotingTestController;

//DBI
List<SomeBean> mockList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>(){{
        add(MockFactoryBean.getMockBean());
}};

@Test
public void testRemoting() {
    try {
        // controller code is not relevant - it simply passes this list 
        // via Spring's HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean to a session facade which then 
        // passes the list further down the SOA stack...
        String result = remotingTestController.createBeanRemotely(mockList); 
        log.debug(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This code bombs in run-time with the following error which makes no sense to me:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.stackoverflow.RemotingIntegrationTest
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
  <<stacktrace snipped>>
  at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
  at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
... 33 more
```

If, however I am to simply omit DBI and use vanilla-style pattern to add an element to a list, as in:

```
    public class RemotingTest {

@Autowired
private RemotingTestController remotingTestController;

List<SomeBean> mockList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>();

@Test
public void testRemoting() {
    mockList.add(MockFactoryBean.getEcopStatusMock());

    try {
    //this block stays the same
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //.....
    }
}
```

}

everything works properly and serializes without a hitch. I've even tried to make the *test* Serializable (*shudders*) but that yielded exactly nothing, as the test died with a even more interesting error - that the `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` should implement Serializable :)

The question is - why is that so? Researching DBI a bit led me to believe that by adding an element to a list this way actually made *two* objects - the expected `ArrayList<T>()` and a new *subclassed* `ArrayList<T>()` object which contained the added element; this somehow confuses Spring's Remoting and dies a gruesome death with a NotSerializableException.

I am not sure, however, if that is what happens behind the scene, so any help in explaining this would be appreciated.

The environment uses the following:

- Spring 3.0.4
- JDK 1.6.0 Update 23
- IceFaces 1.8.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the double-brace initialization syntax creates an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`, and like all anonymous classes, it contains an implicit reference to their parent object (in this case, your test).

In order to be serializable, the parent object (i.e. your test) would also have to be serializable. This is obviously not what you want here.  You'll just have to avoid that syntax, convenient thought it is.

An equally convenient alternative for lists is:

```
List<SomeBean> mockList = Arrays.asList(
    bean1, bean2, bean3
);
```

The DBI syntax is only really compelling when building Maps.

Comment: In this case (DBI with a single element) [`Collections.singletonList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) is a good replacement. For more elements [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) is useful (note that this is a varargs method).

Comment: :sigh: That's too bad, but I guess I have no choice. Thank you both for your insightful comments. Some SO threads mention that we could see some improvements in this area with Project Coin - so will we get new Collection literals with JDK7?

Comment: @Quantum: while collection literals are part of Project Coin, they have been deferred to JDK 8, unfortunately ([source](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/)).

Comment: @Quantam - note, if you constructed that list in a _static_ method, that would also solve serialization the problem.  i still think Arrays.asList and Collections.singletonList are better, though.